# Unable to build bazel project: no such package '@io_bazel_rules_kotlin//kotlin'

Tags: kotlin, bazel

OS:

```
daz@daz:/rom/aosp-mirror/android-test$ uname -ar
Linux daz 5.4.0-28-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 22 17:40:10 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Building with bazel-2.2.0 with the target in the code below:

```
daz@daz:/rom/aosp-mirror/android-test$ bazel-2.2.0 build :axt_m2repository
```

I am trying to build the android-test repo here:

https://github.com/android/android-test

The definition for these rules appears to be this:

```
# Kotlin toolchains
rules_kotlin_version = "4c71740a1b63b785fc90afd8d4d4d5bfda527107"
http_archive(
    name = "io_bazel_rules_kotlin",
    sha256 = "c0ca7b66d9f466067635482592634703bf0a648d51ec958f41796d43ca8256b3",
    strip_prefix = "rules_kotlin-%s" % rules_kotlin_version,
    type = "zip",
    urls = ["https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_kotlin/archive/%s.zip" % rules_kotlin_version],
)
load("@io_bazel_rules_kotlin//kotlin:kotlin.bzl", "kotlin_repositories", "kt_register_toolchains")
kotlin_repositories()
kt_register_toolchains()
```

But I get the following exception when trying to build:

```
ERROR: error loading package '': Encountered error while reading extension file 'kotlin/kotlin.bzl': no such package '@io_bazel_rules_kotlin//kotlin': error loading package 'external': Could not load //external package
```

The full output is here:

```
ERROR: /home/daz/.cache/bazel/_bazel_daz/ff62db25b941d7730a4c94ee1d6f2c41/external/robolectric/bazel/robolectric.bzl:2:5: Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/rom/aosp-mirror/android-test/WORKSPACE", line 130
                robolectric_repositories()
        File "/home/daz/.cache/bazel/_bazel_daz/ff62db25b941d7730a4c94ee1d6f2c41/external/robolectric/bazel/robolectric.bzl", line 381, in robolectric_repositories
                android_all_jars()
        File "/home/daz/.cache/bazel/_bazel_daz/ff62db25b941d7730a4c94ee1d6f2c41/external/robolectric/bazel/robolectric.bzl", line 2, in android_all_jars
                native.maven_jar
no native function or rule 'maven_jar'
Available attributes: aar_import, action_listener, alias, android_binary, android_device, android_device_script_fixture, android_host_service_fixture, android_instrumentation_test, android_library, android_local_test, android_ndk_repository, android_sdk, android_sdk_repository, android_tools_defaults_jar, apple_binary, apple_cc_toolchain, apple_static_library, available_xcodes, bazel_version, bind, cc_binary, cc_host_toolchain_alias, cc_import, cc_libc_top_alias, cc_library, cc_proto_library, cc_test, cc_toolchain, cc_toolchain_alias, cc_toolchain_suite, config_feature_flag, config_setting, constraint_setting, constraint_value, environment, existing_rule, existing_rules, exports_files, extra_action, fdo_prefetch_hints, fdo_profile, filegroup, genquery, genrule, glob, j2objc_library, java_binary, java_import, java_library, java_lite_proto_library, java_package_configuration, java_plugin, java_proto_library, java_runtime, java_runtime_alias, java_test, java_toolchain, java_toolchain_alias, label_flag, label_setting, local_config_platform, local_repository, new_local_repository, ninja_build, ninja_graph, objc_import, objc_library, package_group, package_name, platform, proto_lang_toolchain, proto_library, py_binary, py_library, py_runtime, py_test, register_execution_platforms, register_toolchains, repository_name, sh_binary, sh_library, sh_test, test_suite, toolchain, toolchain_type, xcode_config, xcode_config_alias, xcode_version
ERROR: error loading package '': Encountered error while reading extension file 'kotlin/kotlin.bzl': no such package '@io_bazel_rules_kotlin//kotlin': error loading package 'external': Could not load //external package
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.061s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
```

**WORKAROUND**

Build branch:

```
androidx-test-1.3.0-beta01
```

Use bazel-2.2.0

```
bazel-2.2.0 build :axt_m2repository
```

This is the related issue in the android-test github issue tracker:

https://github.com/android/android-test/issues/626

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you're using the latest version of Bazel and the `android-test` repo.

The `maven_jar` native rule was removed in Bazel 2.0 ([Bazel tracking ticket](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/6799)). Have you tried building with a Bazel version < 2.0 (e.g. [1.2.1](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/tag/1.2.1))?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I don't think I've tried with 1.2.1. I will give that a try. Does it make more sense to migrate to whatever the new method is?

Comment: Definitely. I gave the repo a go yesterday and couldn't reproduce your particular error (on neither 1.2.1 nor 3.1.0). If you still encounter this problem, you'll have to add some info about your Bazel version, OS and the exact target you're trying to build, to see whether this is reproducible.

Comment: The repo says they recommend bazel 2.2.0 - I tried that and it still failed. I added the target to the question.

Comment: Looks like it was the version of bazel and the version of the repository

Comment: Great! I updated the answer, so the next person to run into this has the right answer